# Reading File at Certain Line

Tags: vb.net

How do I start reading the file I want to open up at a certain line? The file I need to open up has a header and the data doesnt start until the second line, but I don't know how to put that into code, I've never done it before.

```
dt.Columns.Add("Mouse Command")
        dt.Columns.Add("Mouse Position")

        Dim delimiter As String = ","
        Using parser As New TextFieldParser(file)
            parser.SetDelimiters(delimiter)
            While Not parser.EndOfData
                ' Read in the fields for the current line
                fields = parser.ReadFields()
                r = dt.NewRow
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your file has a first line that you want to discard and then start parsing the subsequent data you could use the [ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.readline.aspx) method before entering the reading loop

```
Dim delimiter As String = ","
Using parser As New TextFieldParser(file)
    parser.SetDelimiters(delimiter)
    parser.ReadLine()
    While Not parser.EndOfData
        ' Read in the fields for the current line
        fields = parser.ReadFields()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read all the lines first and start processing them on the one you want with this:

```
Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(file)

For i As Integer = 2 To lines.Length - 1
    ' Read in the fields for the current line
    '...
Next
```